# XSL file to copy nodes from one file to another

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to make a merged file of 100's of xml file. The structure of the xml is[image: XML tree]

The structure of every XMl file is the same. I want to just copy all the vouchers part of all the XML files. The XSL code I'm using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 
<xsl:template match="ENVELOPE">
<ENVELOPE>
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:copy-of select="TALLYMESSAGE"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="document('data20140402.xml')/BODY/DATA/TALLYMESSAGE"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="document('data20140403.xml')/BODY/DATA/TALLYMESSAGE"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="document('data20140404.xml')/BODY/DATA/TALLYMESSAGE"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="document('data20140405.xml')/BODY/DATA/TALLYMESSAGE"/>

...

<xsl:copy-of select="document('data20150328.xml')/BODY/DATA/TALLYMESSAGE"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="document('data20150329.xml')/BODY/DATA/TALLYMESSAGE"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="document('data20150330.xml')/BODY/DATA/TALLYMESSAGE"/>
<xsl:copy-of select="document('data20150331.xml')/BODY/DATA/TALLYMESSAGE"/>
</xsl:copy>
</ENVELOPE>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:transform>
```

The Output of the Same is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ENVELOPE>
  <ENVELOPE/>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Comment: Please post an example of the XML input **as code** and show us the expected output. -- P.S. If the root element is `ENVELOPE`, then `document('...')/BODY/DATA/TALLYMESSAGE` will not select anything.

Comment: The input and output have exactly the same structure as in the image, all I want is to copy the vouchers from all the file to one single file.

Comment: All I want to do is see if I can reproduce your problem. I can't do that without having your actual code, XML + XSLT. Please review: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve